# Mongo DB: how to $addToSet custom type element using C# Official driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document with an array of custom type elements:

```
{
    _id: 'id',
    name: '',
    customElements: [
        { _id: 'id',
        name: 'name'}
    ]
}
```

In C# i have corresponding classes:

```
public class CustomElement 
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    CustomElement ()
    {
        id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }
}
```

Using c# official driver, I try to create an Update statement:

```
var update = Update.AddToSet("customElements", new CustomElement { name = "name"});
```

But it shows that it is **not assignable to BsonValue**. How to convert it and $addToSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1, via Wrapped methods that was come with driver version 1.0:

```
  Update.AddToSetWrapped<CustomElement>("customElements",  
                      new CustomElement() { name = "name"); //c# driver >= 1.0
```

Option 2, convert your class to BsonValue yourself via ToBsonDocument() extention method.

```
Update.AddToSet("customElements", new CustomElement() { name = "name"}.ToBsonDocument());
```

Hope this helps.